# Elementary correspondence

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am trying to understand what is the category of finite correspondences over a field $k$The objects of this category will be smooth separated schemes of finite type over a field $k$ and to define the morphisms, first we need to define elementary correspondences. One of the definitions which I have seen is that if $X$ is a smooth connected scheme over $k$ and Y is any scheme over $k$, then an elementary correspondence from $X$ to $Y$ is an irreducible closed subset $W$ of $X\times Y$ whose associated integral subscheme is finite and surjective over $X$. Here, I have a problem. What is the associated integral subscheme means here?
I am quoting this definition from the book “Lecture notes on motivic cohomology”.

Comment: Closed subsets of schemes inherit a canonical "reduced induced scheme structure." This should be familiar from Hartshorne or the like. Since the subset is irreducible, the scheme is furthermore integral.

Comment: @TabesBridges Oh I see. I guess it is true. Thank you.